# How to tell whether a function is probabilty distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

What is the difference between probability density function and probability distribution function?
Also how can I tell whether the given function is distribution function?
for ex: whether this function is probability distribution function?
$$f(x)= \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{2\pi}\arctan(x)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "probability distribution function" is ambiguous.  It could refer to a probability density function (PDF) or a cumulative distribution function (CDF), for instance.  For discrete variables, it can refer to a probability mass function.

A PDF yields non-negative values over its domain, and its integral over its domain is equal to $1$.  Depending on the context, it may include impulses (that is, Dirac delta functions representing a non-zero probability of holding a specific value).

A CDF, which is the integral of the corresponding PDF, takes on values in the interval $[0, 1]$ over its domain, and is non-decreasing.  Typically, it is assumed that it has a limit of $0$ toward the minimum of the domain, and a limit of $1$ toward the maximum of the domain.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say $f(x)$ is some function. The conditions that qualify it as a bona fide Probability Density Function (PDF) are:

1. $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$.
2. $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx = 1$.

So you need only to verify that the function in question has these properties to conclude that it is a PDF for some random variable.